# Rails ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): delete_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've been searching Google and no one has come across this problem yet. I am writing a `has_and_belongs_to_many` custom sql, and it won't let me specify `:delete_sql`. Here's my code so far:

```
class Foo
  has_many :students,
           :class_name => 'User',
           :finder_sql => 'SELECT users.* FROM users, groups, students_groups WHERE users.id = students_groups.student_id AND students_groups.group_id = groups.id AND groups.course_period_id = #{id}',
           :delete_sql => 'DELETE FROM students_groups WHERE students_groups.student_id = #{record.id} AND students_groups.group_id IN (SELECT groups.id FROM groups WHERE groups.course_period_id = #{id})'
end
```

I found [the documentation on delete_sql for has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)... I think I'm following them exactly, but I am getting the following error when I try to use this class:

```
Foo.new
```

But it's raising the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): delete_sql
```

I don't think it makes a difference, but I'm using Rails v3.0.5

Should I fill out a bug report or am I missing the obvious?

Comment: The page you listed only lists `:delete_sql` under the HABTM heading, none of the other associations mention it. I couldn't find any references in the `associations.rb` file to say why it wasn't supported for the other association types, but it feels like a missing feature to me.

Comment: @seth...In the API, `:delete_sql` is provided as an option for `_and_belongs_to_many` and it is not provided as an option for `has_many`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that I just lie to rails and tell it that its a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association...